# Comparing a string and an object property

Tags: java, android, string, object, comparison

I'am trying to compare a string with an object property using .equals(), but the condition keeps failing even if its true.
I've tried using trim() to get rid off trailling spaces but still fails.

Heres my code:

```
if (status) {
        inventoryList = allInventory.getInventory();
        assert assetId != null;
        for (Inventory inventory : inventoryList) {
            if (assetId.trim().equals(inventory.getProductCode().trim())) {

                //get the current quantity that exists

                new_quantity.setValue(0);

                new_quantity.setMaxValue(inventory.getQuantity());
                inventoryId = inventory.getId();
                return;

            } else {
                // new_quantity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                decrement.setEnabled(false);
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alert.setTitle("Product not found ");
                // prevent cancel of AlertDialog on click of back button and outside touch
                alert.setCancelable(false);
                alert.setMessage("Product is not in inventory. Do you want to continue scanning?");

                alert.setNegativeButton("No", (dialog, which) -> {
                            onBackPressed();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                );
                alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialog, which) -> {
                    Intent scanAsset = new Intent(this, ScanActivity.class);
                    scanAsset.putExtra("building", building);
                    scanAsset.putExtra("room", room);
                    scanAsset.putExtra("department", depart);
                    scanAsset.putExtra("TAG", "E");
                    startActivity(scanAsset);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                });
                AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
                dialog.show();
            }

        }
```

Comment: A couple of notes:
1) Specifically which line are you having trouble with? Sorry, but I'm not going to parse the entire context of this code to try to help with a simple `.equals()` issue. 

2) Are you sure you're comparing two strings? If one object is not a string it will always be `false`.

3) You could also try overriding `equals()` on your custom object (if you're using one) so you can compare both objects without converting one to a `String`. This is definitely not recommended if you're not using a custom object here.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out to the oracle docs, which says:

> Compares this string to the specified object. The **result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object** that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

[image]

Comment: what does it mean by a String object?

Comment: Basically, String is not a primitive datatype in Java.
It is an object made of char sequence.
I hope that is what you are asking for

Answer (score 0):

try to use equalsIgnoreCase() instead of equals